# Why are some JSON attributes omitted?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-devtools

I have a JSON object that I'm working with. It's the result of an HTTP GET request.

The **expected** results are the following:

```
{
  "name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "authors": {
    "collection": "users",
    "via": "IDPid"
  },
  "id": {
    "type": "integer",
    "autoIncrement": true,
    "primaryKey": true,
    "unique": true
  }
}
```

The **actual** results are the following (The `authors` attribute is omitted):

```
{
  "name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "id": {
    "type": "integer",
    "autoIncrement": true,
    "primaryKey": true,
    "unique": true
  }
}
```

Why did it take out the authors attribute?

However, when I debug this in Chrome, though the `authors` attributes is still omitted, I am able to execute `console.log(response.authors)` and it reads it fine.

Also, when I go to the Network tab on Chrome dev tools to see the response of the HTTP request, it shows the missing attribute in the response body just fine.

Comment: Can you give us a working example? Or at least tell us how you are able to view the "**actual**" results?

Comment: Where are you seeing the json data without the authors attribute?  The network tab is showing you the data that's coming to you, verbatim.  That's what's coming back in response to your GET request.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. It was because `console.log` doesn't run right away. It runs after some time. I had other code that modified the object, but console.log ran after that code for some reason, even though I wrote it before.